# Which tools generate a repository dump with leading slashes in path headers?

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump, svndumpfilter

SVNBook tells that a repository dump generated with `svnadmin dump` never includes leading slashes in `Node-path` and `Node-copyfrom-path` headers.

It also [tells that some 3-rd party tools (scripts?) can generate Subversion repository dumps **with** leading slashes in these headers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#idp14748560).

Inconsistent usage of slashes in these headers (as far as I understand, it can happen after combining 2 repository dumps generated via different tools) can cause issues when filtering a repository dump.

So which tools generate a repository dump with leading slashes in path headers? **In what case a repository dump can have an inconsistent leading slashes usage?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SVN-DumpReloc](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc) Perl script generates leading slashes in `Node-path` and `Node-copyfrom-path` headers.

So, combining repository dumps, when one of them was processed with *SVN-DumpReloc* will create a dump file with inconsistent usage of slashes.